# How does the strandrender work?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been trying to work with particle hair using a very simple model. I had just set up a very simple material for the hair and when I render it(using internal engine), it turns out very odd:
[image]

so I hit the strand render checkbox and the hair seems to be fine but there's one another problem, the head pops up in the render:
[image]

no matter I turn up the alpha value of material, texture etc, I cannot fix it? How does the strandrender work and how can I fix this?

the settings are:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

they're mostly left at default.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the render?

Comment: we can see a big outline of the head through the hair(in the second render) which does look so weird. I'd like to know if there's any way to omit that.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it personally.

Comment: could you show the material settings you use for the strands ?

Comment: @Flaeon,The second render shows a big outline of the bald head underneath which is not shown in the first render.

Comment: @nantille, the third(hair texture) the settings that I used to bring out the texture for hair, I posted others if it would be useful.

Comment: In the settings of your hair, there is transparency in the gradient. So this means that at some point, your strand will be transparent and show what is below it – the skin and head outline. I guess this is the culprit behind that unwanted result. What happens if you remove transparency from your strand material ?

Comment: @nantille, suspecting the same thing, I actually turned on the alpha values of everything possible, but didn't work. Does strand rendering particle hair always behave like this?